# Running WebDriver tests in parallel using testng.xml

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I'm trying to run WebDriver tests in parallel using testng.xml. I'm able to run testng tests in parallel by using parameter **parallel="tests"** but running with following paramters, **"methods", "classes"** is not working.

**testng.xml**

```
    <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
   <test name="Cart">
    <classes>
       <class name="com.tests1.Minus1">
       </class>       
    </classes>
   </test> 
  <test name="Checkout">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.tests2.AddA"/>
      <class name="com.tests2.AddB"/>
      <class name="com.tests2.AddC"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="MBB">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.tests3.Mult1"/>
      <class name="com.tests3.Mult2"/>      
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I tried with these versions **6.0.1, 5.9, 5.14.1, 6.3.1, 5.14.10, 5.10.0.1, 6.3, 5.14.6, 5.5**. It didn’t seem to work. I also increased thread count to 100, but no behavior difference.

Can anyone please point out what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What happens now?

Comment: Does it also not work when you use "-parallel methods" from command line?

Comment: Actually I'm running these tests through Eclipse, so not using commandline. But I suspect that it won't run even through commandline. Right now, when I run tests they run sequentially instead of parallel if I use parallel=methods or parallel=classes. But runs in parallel for parallel=tests

Comment: A wild guess, Can you keep attribute, `parallel="methods"` at the test level instead of suite level and check?

Comment: Tarun, I tried this by placing parallel="methods" at the test level but it didn't help.

Comment: I tried with these versions 6.0.1, 5.9, 5.14.1, 6.3.1, 5.14.10, 5.10.0.1, 6.3, 5.14.6, 5.5. It didn’t seem to work. I also increased thread count to 100, but no behavior difference.

Comment: This might help - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/testng-users/iwCUpcN_O2A

Comment: @RatedAbstract How you are able to run the tests parallel..for me it's not working.All the test cases are in running in one browser only even 2 browsers are opening parallel. Thanks.
Smita

Answer (score 3):

Place this in your `test` or `suite` tag: `preserve-order="false"`

If this is not in there, parallel classes will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your goal.  Using your testng.xml, when I ran with `parallel='tests'`, each group of tests under a `test` tag ran sequentially, but the three `test` tags ran in parallel.  Is that enough parallelism for you, or is your intent to run all six test classes simultaneously?  If the latter, have you considered putting all six test classes under the same `test` tag?

Answer (score 0):

For each suite you have to specify parallel="classes" and thread-count then testcases under that suite will run in parallel

Below is working testng.xml. u can give a try surely it will work since its working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
<test name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="demo.suite.GoogleTest"/>
  <class name="demo.suite.YahooTest"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```